# Initialize the server.js then within the HTML page call a function from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

**OVERVIEW**

I am trying to create a Dapp with Ethereum and the course I am following (Udacity Blockchain Nanodegree Program) is asking us to create a HTML page from where a User using the page's buttons can interact with the Smart Contract. I am a beginner with HTML and anything related to hosting servers and routing, etc. So, I created two really basic functions in the Javascript file to practice how to call them and later on replace it with the correct web3 functions.

**PROBLEM**

The thing is that I've used a separated Javascript file for my functions and when I try to call those functions from the HTML file it doesn't work.
I've read that the main reason is that the functionFile.js is not in the server.js and it should have a route.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why my code doesn't work? Could you explain it so that a beginner like me can understand it?
2. What is the code that I need to implement in server.js that will solve these errors and make the page work as intended?

**PROJECT DIRECTORY STRUCTURE**

[image]

**SERVER.JS CODE**

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const PORT = 8080;

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;

    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(PORT);

});
```

**TEST.JS CODE**

```
function letMeCallYou() {
    alert("Bazinga!!!  you called letMeCallYou");
}

function myfunction() {
     document.write("welcome to Javatpoint");
}
```

**INDEX.HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>StarNotary DAPP Front End</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <style>
    input {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>StarNotary DAPP</h1>
    <h3 id='name'>Star Name: </h3>
    <hr>
    <h3 id='owner'>Star Owner: </h3>
    <hr>
    <h3>Claim Star</h3>
    <hr>
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    <button id="test" onclick="letMeCallYou()">Testing External Javascript library</button>
    <script src="scripts/test.js"></script>
    <script>letMeCallYou();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ERROR SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve my problem after modifying the server.js file folder. Here is my updated project file architecture with the updated server.js code.

**PROJECT ARCHITECTURE**

[image]

**SERVER.JS CODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// THIS LINE WAS THE SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, () =>{
    console.log('APPLICATION INITIALIZED....');
});
```

**INDEX.HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>StarNotary DAPP Front End</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <style>
    input {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>StarNotary DAPP</h1>
    <h3 id='name'>Star Name: </h3>
    <hr>
    <h3 id='owner'>Star Owner: </h3>
    <hr>
    <h3>Claim Star</h3>
    <hr>
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    <button id="test" onclick="letMeCallYou()">Testing External Javascript library</button>
    <script src='./scripts/app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EXECUTION SCREENSHOT**

[image]